# Python algorithm: What is the complexity of my algorithm and how can I optimize it?

Tags: python, performance, optimization, big-o

I'm trying to accomplish a task in which you are given n (the size of a square chessboard, queens (the squares they occupy), and queries(a list of coordinates).  I am to return a list of Boolean values saying whether or not each query is attackable by any of the queens.  I know my algorithm works but I also know that it isn't efficient "enough".  Through research, I'm guessing that the complexity is O(queens*queries)?  So that's my first questions, is it O(queens*queries), if not why?  Second, does anyone have an idea how I can optimize it possibly even down to O(queens + queries)?  I apologize if this is a rudimentary question, but I am mainly self-taught and don't have anyone I can ask this.  Thanks in advance!

```
def squaresUnderQueenAttack(n, queens, queries):
    output = []
    for i in queries:
        attackable = False
        for j in queens:
            if attackable != True and (i[0]==j[0] or i[1]==j[1] or abs(i[0]-j[0])==abs(i[1]-j[1])):
                attackable = True
                break
        output.append(attackable)
    return output
```

Comment: No, do **not** post images of code. Post the code as formatted text, which it already way. I'm rolling back the edit.

Comment: If you indent your block of code with 4 extra spaces it will display correctly. You can also enclose snippets of code or math within your main text with back ticks to get them to display correctly, instead of converting asterisks to italics.

Comment: @Rawing I beg to differ, I'm a programmer, possibly a bad one, and an excellent OCR device (if only I'd find my glasses, umph)

Comment: @gboffi a *very deep* neural net, you might say :)

Comment: Thank you for the heads up, I didn't know what was going on so I kept editing until it looked right...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current code is *O(queens * queries)*. You can improve it to *O(queens + queries)*.

Make three arrays, each with 8 elements. Call them *row*, *col*, *diagleft*, and *diagright*.

Look at each queen, if it's in row 0, set that spot in *row* to true. If it's in col 3, set that spot to *col* in true. Label the diagonals 0-7 and make appropriate marks in them as well.

Now the arrays indicate all of the rows, columns, and diagonals that have queens.

Now, look at each query and check to see if any of the array entries corresponding to its location are marked true. If so, then a queen threatens it.

Note that in big-O notation, we're interested in which factor "dominates" the run-time, so the above solution is probably more appropriately thought of as operating in *O(max(queens,queries))* time. That is, if you have many queries, the queens calculation takes only a little time. Similarly, if you have many queens and few queries, that operation will take most of your time.

Comment: You are right, but also, some authors will measure it as `O(max(queens, queries))`. Do you know which method is better?

Comment: His question asks for the bigO of his current code sample. I believe it should be specified in your answer that his current complexity is O(queens * queries).

Comment: @VMRuiz: A good point, and a better choice than _O(queens+queries)_. I've edited the answer to include mention of that.

Comment: Thank you!!! This was extremely helpful and very well explained.  I love this community!!!

Comment: @pickard151: You're welcome. Thank you for clearly explaining your question and including well-formatted source code showing your current progress; good questions make good answers. If my answer's addressed your question well, feel free to up-vote it. If you'd like to mark it as the "Accepted Answer" there's a check-mark outline you can click. Otherwise, you can also wait to see if additional answers come in.